# Visual Studio Code and Java issue, not compiling nor java command accepted

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

i am having an issue with Java and Visual Studio Code, I have followed the java tutorial from Visual Studio Code, link here : https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-tutorial.

My issue is that I can't run anything java related, in the console javac is not recognized, when I go to the command palette and try to run a java command it print the error in the image linked and every time I launch VSC it tell me that Extension host terminated unexpectedly.

In the link, i'll put a screen of my java home settings.

Things I've tried :

- Uninstalling and reinstalling
- Using the installer in the tutorial
- Changing the '\' to '/' in the path to java home
- Having the same Java: Home in User and Workspace

[Java Home path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Ah9i.png)
[Issue with Java](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5fNTe.png)

Answer (score 0):

Uninstalling VSC, deleting the .vscode in the User folder and then reinstalling solved the issue, I don't understand why on the first install it got it wrong, but the issue is solved.